# Enviar value de elemento select usando sesiones

Tags: php, html

Quiero pasar los value de un elemento select de una página principal a otra página y al regresar a la página principal que me recuerde el option seleccionado

Quiero hacerlo con enlaces y usando una sesión, en lugar de usar un botón input type submit y un formulario, es posible?

Esta es la página principal

```html
<?

 session_start();
 //$_SESSION['var'] = "hola que hay";

 echo "<select name=casillas>";
 echo "<option value=op1>Opción 1</option>";
 echo "<option value=op2>Opción 2</option></select>";

 $_SESSION['var'] = $_SESSION['casillas'];

?>


<br><br><a href="pru2.php">Ir a página 2</a>
```

Y esta sería la página secundaria

```html
<?

 session_start();
 echo "Valor de la variable: " . $_SESSION['var'];

?>

<br><br><a href="pru.php">Volver</a>
```

Si envío una variable creada por mí (en el ejemplo el string "hola que hay") se envía correctamente, pero no consigo enviar los values del elemento select

Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Gracias

Comment: jamás inicializas `$_SESSION['casillas']` probablemente por eso no regrese nada

Comment: Cómo inicializo casillas? Cómo puedo almacenar el option de un elemento select en una variable de sesión???

Comment: Cómo puedo guardar op1 y op2, que son los value del select, en variables de sesión?

Comment: Si no envías el formulario, no se podría almacenar en una variable de session

Comment: Te has planteado hacerlo del lado cliente? Con Javascript y localStorage. Mediante control de eventos de JS/JQuery.

Comment: No conocía esa opción, gracias Eduard!